# Raspbian Stretch - git clone free memory

Tags: raspbian-stretch, git

Please consider the output here below:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.14.30+ #1102 Mon Mar 26 16:20:05 BST 2018 armv6l GNU/Linux
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ git --version
git version 2.17.0.252.gfe0a9eaf3
pi@raspberrypi:~/git $ sudo git gc --aggressive --prune=now
Counting objects: 242693, done.
error: pack-objects died of signal 9510)
error: failed to run repack
```

How can I get rid of the error?

@eftshift0
suggested cmd line output (avoided "sudo"):
1) pi@raspberrypi:~/git $ strace git

```
execve("/usr/bin/git", ["git"], [/* 58 vars */]) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x1501000
uname({sysname="Linux", nodename="raspberrypi", ...}) = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap2(NULL, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb6fc6000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = 0
open("/etc/ld.so.preload", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
.....
write(1, "grow, mark and tweak your common"..., 41) = 41
write(1, "   branch     List, create, or d"..., 47) = 47
write(1, "   checkout   Switch branches or"..., 60) = 60
write(1, "   commit     Record changes to "..., 47) = 47
write(1, "   diff       Show changes betwe"..., 73) = 73
write(1, "   merge      Join two or more d"..., 62) = 62
write(1, "   rebase     Reapply commits on"..., 57) = 57
write(1, "   tag        Create, list, dele"..., 74) = 74
write(1, "\n", 1)                       = 1
write(1, "collaborate (see also: git help "..., 43) = 43
write(1, "   fetch      Download objects a"..., 64) = 64
write(1, "   pull       Fetch from and int"..., 81) = 81
write(1, "   push       Update remote refs"..., 63) = 63
write(1, "\n", 1)                       = 1
write(1, "'git help -a' and 'git help -g' "..., 133) = 133
write(1, "to read about a specific subcomm"..., 48) = 48
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

2) pi@raspberrypi:~/git $ strace git --aggresive --prune=now

```
execve("/usr/bin/git", ["git", "--aggressive", "--prune=now"], [/* 58 vars */]) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x7be000
uname({sysname="Linux", nodename="raspberrypi", ...}) = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap2(NULL, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb6fd4000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = 0
open("/etc/ld.so.preload", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
....
open("/usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_CTYPE", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=198372, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 198372, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0xb6c0a000
close(3)                                = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [PIPE], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[PIPE], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0xb6e026b0}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
open("/usr/share/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/C.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/C/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "unknown option: --aggressive\n", 29unknown option: --aggressive
) = 29
write(2, "usage: git [--version] [--help] "..., 315usage: git [--version] [--help] [-C <path>] [-c <name>=<value>]
           [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]
           [-p | --paginate | --no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]
           [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]
           <command> [<args>]
) = 315
exit_group(129)                         = ?
+++ exited with 129 +++
```

looking at the output here above I eliminated the option "aggressive" (also "sudo" results useless as the output I got is identical)

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/git $ git gc --prune=now
Counting objects: 242693, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (61175/61175), done.
Writing objects: 100% (242693/242693), done.
Total 242693 (delta 179335), reused 242693 (delta 179335)
Checking connectivity: 242693, done.
```

Comment: Probably unrelated but: Why are you using sudo to run git on a repo?
 Then, can you run **git fsck**? Also, what happens if you run the last git command with strace (sudo strace git --aggresive --prune=now)? What happens if you don'tuse the --aggresive and --prune=now options?

Comment: pi@raspberrypi:~/git $ git fsck
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
warning in tag d6602ec5194c87b0fc87103ca4d67251c76f233a: missingTaggerEntry: invalid format - expected 'tagger' line
Checking objects: 100% (242693/242693), done.
Checking connectivity: 242693, done.

Comment: I have saved the output of the two commands in txt files. Is there a way I can upload them? If not possible I'll paste in this box as a comment, but splitting in slices 600 characters long.

Comment: I don't see anything funky in git fsck. If you ran strace, just the last lines should be enough. If they provide any _interesting_ information, you could just edit the question you made and add those lines saying they belong to strace and stuff. And why are you using sudo? You didn't tell us.